# mvc partial view autocomplete using modal jquery not displaying data in textboxfor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have review many examples but have not been able to find an example to help me figure out my issue.

I have everything working up to the jquery autocomplete response.  But the data is not showing in the textboxfor.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ship_To_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div id="ShipToName" class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Ship_To_Name, new { @class = "autocomplete_with_hidden", data_url = Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Customer") })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ship_To_Code, new { id = "ShipToCode" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ship_To_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Here is how the partial view is being called.**

```
     <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/WebOrder/CreateShipTo" id="btnCreate">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </a>

   <!-- modal placeholder-->
   <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**jquery**

The below code is working but I can't get the data to display.

```
$(function () {

    $('#myModalContent').on('keyup', '#Ship_To_Name.autocomplete_with_hidden', function (event) {

        var target = $(this);

        target.autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var url = $(this.element).data('url');

                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: { "term": request.term },

                    success: function (data) {
                         response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.id
                            };
                        }))
                    }
                });
            },
        });

    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    var model = db.Customers
                   .Where(m => term == null || m.Customer_Name.StartsWith(term))
                   .Take(10)
                   .Select(m => new
                   {
                       label = m.Customer_Name,
                       id = m.Ship_To_Code
                   }).ToArray();

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult CreateShipTo(WebOrderVM webOrderVM)
    {
        return PartialView("_AddShipToInfo", webOrderVM);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a little problem here. You are registering the jquery ui auto complete functionality on every key up event on that that textbox ! I don't think that is needed. You may simply register it once.

Also, to enable the autocomplete, you need minimal amount of code as such

```
$(function () {

    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: $("#Name").data('url'),
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {

          //If you want to do something custom on the select event,
          //  you may do it here
          // Ex : $("#SomeDiv").html(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
});
```

This should work as lonog as your action method returns you the data.

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    var model = db.Customers
                   .Where(m => term == null || m.Customer_Name.StartsWith(term))
                   .Take(10)
                   .Select(m => new
                   {
                       label = m.Customer_Name,
                       id = m.Ship_To_Code
                   }).ToArray();

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you want the auto complete to work with dynamically loaded content, you should register the auto complete after you inject the content to DOM

Quick example

```
$.get(someUrlToGetDynamicContent,function(res){

   $("#SomeContainer").append(res);
   $(".someClassNameForTheTextBox").autocomplete({
                    source: urlToGetTheAutoCompleteData,
                    minLength: 1,
                    select: function (event, ui) {  }
   });

})
```

Comment: Hi Shyju this is a partial view that is being loaded dynamically. The function will not work if I am not using the following event line of code $('#myModalContent').on('keyup', '#Ship_To_Name.autocomplete_with_hidden', function (event) {

Comment: You should re register once you get the content and load it dynamically to your DOM.

Comment: Would you have an example of what you are talking about.

Comment: I added more detail on the partial view using the modal.  I hope someone can help me figure out my issue.